# Не меняет activity

Tags: android, activity

Код должен сменять активность на вторую, но он этого не делает. Не могу разобраться в чём проблема.

```
package com.example.alexey.projectarmytap;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener{

private static int counter;
private static Seifim seifim;
Button btnCreateNewTofes, btnNewMail;
DBHelper helper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
ListView listview1;
final ArrayList<Seifim> list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter adapter = null;
ListView listview = null;
String mailadress = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    ArrayAdapter<Seifim> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Seifim>(this, R.layout.layout_list, R.id.textViewnew, list);
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Seifim seifim = (Seifim) intent.getSerializableExtra("seifim");
    mailadress = intent.getStringExtra("mailadress"); ///////////// not sure

    btnCreateNewTofes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createNewTofes);
    btnCreateNewTofes.setOnClickListener(this);
    listview1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);

    if (seifim != null) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO items (misparRehev, shemEhida, kamutKilometrim, date, sugTipul, manoa, delek, higui, blamim, zmigim, hashmal, hashlada, abs, mivhan, totzaa) VALUES ('" +
                seifim.getMisparRehev() + "','" + seifim.getShemEhida() + "','" + seifim.getSugTipul() + "','" + seifim.getDate() + "','" + seifim.getKamutKilometrim() + "','" +
                seifim.getManoa() + "','" + seifim.getDelek() + "','" + seifim.getHigui() + "','" + seifim.getBlamim() + "','" + seifim.getZmigim() + "','" + seifim.getHashmal() + "','" +
                seifim.getHashlada() + "','" + seifim.getAbs() + "','" + seifim.getMivhan() + "','" + seifim.getTotzaa() + "')";
        System.out.println("sql=" +sql);
        db.execSQL(sql);
        sql = "SELECT * FROM items";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null, null);
        System.out.println("cursor count: " + cursor.getCount());

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            seifim = new Seifim();
            lemaleSeifim(seifim,cursor);
            list.add(seifim);
        }
        Collections.reverse(list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(listview);
    }
    else {
        String sql2 = "SELECT * FROM items";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql2, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            seifim = new Seifim();
            lemaleSeifim(seifim, cursor);
            list.add(seifim);
        }
        Collections.reverse(list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(listview);

    }
    final Seifim totzaaShelSeifim = seifim;
    listview1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowSeifimActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("list", list);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            Seifim fin = list.get(position);
            int finMr = fin.getMisparRehev();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    if (v.getId()==R.id.listview1){
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo ad = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        counter = ((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo).position;
        menu.setHeaderTitle("choose:");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Send");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
    }
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if (item.getTitle()=="Send"){
        Seifim seifim = list.get(counter);
        int id = seifim.getId();
        sendSeifim(id);
    }
    else if (item.getTitle()=="Delete"){
        Seifim seifim = list.get(counter);
        int id = seifim.getId();
        if (deleteSeifim(id)>0){
            list.remove(counter);
            updateBd();
        }
    }
    return false;
}


private Seifim lemaleSeifim(Seifim seifim, Cursor cursor) {
    seifim.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
    seifim.setMisparRehev(cursor.getInt(1));
    seifim.setKamutKilometrim(cursor.getInt(2));
    seifim.setShemEhida(cursor.getString(3));
    seifim.setSugTipul(cursor.getString(4));
    seifim.setDate(cursor.getString(5));
    seifim.setManoa(cursor.getString(6));
    seifim.setDelek(cursor.getString(7));
    seifim.setHigui(cursor.getString(8));
    seifim.setBlamim(cursor.getString(9));
    seifim.setZmigim(cursor.getString(10));
    seifim.setHashmal(cursor.getString(11));
    seifim.setHashlada(cursor.getString(12));
    seifim.setAbs(cursor.getString(13));
    seifim.setMivhan(cursor.getString(14));
    seifim.setTotzaa(cursor.getString(15));
    return seifim;
}

public int deleteSeifim (int id){
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql2 = "SELECT * FROM items";
    return db.delete("items", "ID=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
}
public void sendSeifim (int id){
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql2 = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE id="+id+"";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql2, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        seifim = new Seifim();
        seifim = lemaleSeifim(seifim, cursor);
        String mail = getmail(seifim);
        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{mailadress});
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "tofes tipul");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mail);
        email.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "which client?"));
    }
}
public void updateBd(){
    list.clear();
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    ArrayAdapter<Seifim> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Seifim>(this, R.layout.layout_list, R.id.textViewnew, list);
    String sql2 = "SELECT * FROM items";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql2, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        seifim = new Seifim();
        lemaleSeifim(seifim, cursor);
        list.add(seifim);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Collections.reverse(list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(listview);
}
private String getmail(Seifim seifim){
    return " מספר רכב: " + seifim.getMisparRehev() + " יחידה: " +seifim.getShemEhida()+"" + " קילומטרז': " + seifim.getKamutKilometrim() + " נוצר בתאריך: " + seifim.getDate() + " סוג טיפול: " + seifim.getSugTipul();
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == btnCreateNewTofes) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (view == btnNewMail) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, mailSend.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}}
```

Код ошибки:

```
 Process: com.example.alexey.projectarmytap, PID: 10876
              android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.alexey.projectarmytap/com.example.alexey.projectarmytap.SecondActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4522)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4490)
                  at com.example.alexey.projectarmytap.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:193)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 3):

Ошибку нашёл. Нужно было указать вторую активность в AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".ShowSeifimActivity"/>/
</application>
```